# Official Google Maps Flutter Plugin - Touch events changing map widget position

Tags: ios, google-maps, dart, flutter

I'm experiencing a really strange issue on Google maps plugin, released by flutter. After adding markers from an API response, the map pan gestures move the widget around and sometimes do not allow other UI elements to receive touches. Plugin version is `google_maps_flutter: ^0.2.0+5`This is on iOS and the widget tree is:

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
  new Container(
      height: 300,
      child: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center ?? LatLng(0, 0),
            zoom: 15.0,
          ),
          gestureRecognizers: Set()..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer())))),
  new Positioned(
      bottom: 16,
      left: 16,
      right: 16,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: moreInfoAnimationTime,
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(_moreInfoOffset, 0, 0),
        child: tappedOffer != null
            ? new Container(
                height: OffersMapItemView.HEIGHT,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
                child: new OffersMapItemView(
                  tappedOffer,
                  onTap: (OffersAndPromo offer) => this.goToOfferDetails(offer),
                ),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    new BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black45,
                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : new Text(''),
      ))
]);
```

Where the positioned widget contains a custom action for tapping markers and to display a custom info window.

flutter doctor output:

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.2.3-pre.67, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G5019, locale
    en-GB)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

[image]